# What is the difference between UserManager created using HttpContext vs DBContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

What is the difference between these two methods to create UserManager?

```
var userManager1 = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var userManager2 = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext));
```

The [`IdentitySamples`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1) application uses `HttpContext.GetOwinContext` for both `UserManager` and `RoleManager`. Also `AccountController` in default MVC 5 application template uses `HttpContext.GetOwinContext` but when I create a new controller which uses `UserManager`. It uses `db` (the `ApplicationDbContext`)

**Default `AccountController`**

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set { _userManager = value; }
}

//can be used as
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(UserManager.Users.ToList());
}
```

Any new controller

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

//can be used as
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Users.ToList());
}
```

Which of the two methods should be used in which case?

Comment: IMO, you should not use either of these methods. Instead, set up the `UserManager<UserType>` as a dependency in an Inversion of Control container, and then constructor inject it where it is needed. Other than that, the `UserManager` gives you more behavior than a plain `DbContext`, such as password hashing and email confirmation features.